# Wie kann man seine Fehler während eines Gesprächs identifizieren oder identifizieren lassen?

Tags: standard-german

Die Höflichkeit spielt eine große Rolle in Deutschland, aber manchmal ist das nicht gut für Nichtmuttersprachler. Niemand korrigiert mich im Alltag, wenn ich etwas grammatikalisch falsch sage. (Ich bin mir ganz sicher, dass sie mich manchmal überhaupt nicht verstehen). Dabei würde mir jede Korrektur beim Lernen der Sprache helfen.

Was kann man machen (oder sagen), um ein konstruktives Feedback von  Muttersprachlern zu seinen grammatikalischen Fehlern zu bekommen? Oder Hinweise um seine Fehler selbst zu identifizieren?

Comment: @Ad Infinitum, ich habe kleine Fehler in deiner Frage korrigiert und manche Sätze umformuliert um sie verständlicher zu machen. Wenn du Fragen zu Veränderungen hast, schreib mir einfach einen Kommentar (mit @...) unter deine Frage.

Comment: Wegen @Ludi s "Sie" und meinem "du" noch den Hinweis auf folgende Diskussion: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/how-is-the-familiar-you-du-used-in-online-conversations

Comment: Oder auch: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/36/umgangsformen-du-oder-sie

Comment: @Ludi, das war nicht als Kritik gemeint, sondern einfach als Hinweis das sich Kommunikationsformen im Internet, bei Emails und und offline unterscheiden kann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ihre Frage überrascht mich sehr! Meiner Erfahrung nach sind wir (viel mehr als andere Völker) darauf erpicht Andere zu korrigieren. Keinesfalls nehme ich mich selbst aus! Ich ärgere mich oft im Nachhinein darüber, wie wenig wir die Bemühungen der Lernenden würdigen! Sie sollten mal Griechen oder Asiaten sehen! Diese Völker loben einen für jeden noch so kläglichen Versuch!

Da ich aber nun asiatische Sprachen lerne und Ihr Problem nur zu gut kenne, kann ich Ihnen einige gute Ratschläge erteilen.

- Weisen Sie darauf hin, wie wichtig es Ihnen ist ihr Deutsch zu verbessern! Tun Sie es alle paar Wochen!
- Erwähnen Sie ggf. Prüfungen und Fälle in denen Sie Ihre Deutschkenntnisse bitter benötigen!
- Danken Sie für Korrekturen!
- Finden Sie mit Geduld einen guten **Tandempartner**! Er wird Ihnen mehr helfen als alle Anderen, denn er erwartet das selbe von Ihnen.

Ein passender Satz lautet:

> Ich muss unbedingt mein Deutsch verbessern. Bitte weisen Sie mich auf Fehler hin. Ich bin Ihnen dafür dankbar!

Diese Ratschläge sollten Ihnen helfen, benutzen Sie aber auch Ihren Menschenverstand. ;) Im Supermarkt hat der Kassierer keine Zeit für Ihr Sprachproblem!

Übrigens dürfen Sie nicht zu viel erwarten. Es ist sehr anstrengend jemanden ständig zu korrigieren. Streben Sie einige Korrekturen pro Tag an, erwarten Sie jedoch Sorgfalt von Ihrem Tandempartner!

Comment: Danke schön für Ihre ausführliche Antwort. Ich bin ungefähr seit 3,5 Jahren in Deutschland und ich habe immer etwas mit den Muttersprachlern zu tun aber bisher bin ich 2 Mal korrigiert worden. Und mehrere Male habe ich darauf hingewiesen, dass ich nicht persönlich nehme, wenn Sie meinen Fehler korrigieren würden. Unter Deutschen höre ich manchmal, dass Sie den anderen Muttersprachler korrigieren, wenn ein einen Fehler macht. Vielleicht wollen Sie nicht als **Besserwisser** aussehen?

Comment: Meine Erfahrung ist, dass Muttersprachler gern einander verbessern  (z.B. bei Abweichungen vom Hochdeutsch durch Dialekt), aber bei Nichtmuttersprachlern vorsichtig mit Verbesserungen sind um nicht unhöflich zu sein.

Comment: @Iris Exakt. Meine Erfahrung ist auch so, wie Sie gesagt haben. Vielleicht denken sie, er/sie ist in einer anderen Kultur aufgewachsen und sie wissen nicht, wie ich über eine Verbesserung reagiere?

Comment: @AdInfinitum sagen Sie nicht *ich nehme es nicht persönlich* , das lässt viele glauben, es sei Ihnen doch unangenehm. Bitten Sie um Korrekturen!

Comment: @Ludi, naja, nicht immer ist der unterschied zwischen Dialekt und Fehler klar, z.B. "Ich bin größer wie du" ist für mich schwäbischer Dialekt und für den Rest von Deutschland ein Fehler.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Bei Muttersprachler werden auch gerne Versprecher korrigiert. Dabei ist einem bewusst, dass der andere es natürlich weiß, wie's richtig ist und es dem anderen wahrscheinlich sogar selbst aufgefallen ist. Aber solche Anlässe werden gerne genommen, um darüber ein Witzchen zu machen. Gegenüber Ausländern sind wir deswegen zurückhaltend, weil es durchaus auch einige gibt, die es nervt, wenn man ständig korrigiert wird. Als Nicht-Muttersprachler sind Fehler ja prinzipiell gang und gäbe, wenngleich es i. d. R. unbedeutende Fehler sind.

Comment: @Em1 Ich denke, ich muss mehr betonen, dass ich es nicht persönlich nehme, wenn Sie mich korrigieren würden.

Comment: @Iris sehr interessant. Dabei sollten sie es gerade andersrum machen! Kein vernünftiger Mensch korrigiert absichtlich einen Bayern, der *das Teller* sagt. Erstens, weil Dialekte wichtig sind und zweitens dem Selbsterhaltungstrieb folgend;)  EDIT:  die Grenze zwischen Fehler und Dialektform ist wohl subjektiv, die Tatsache, dass ein Dialekt vorliegt jedoch für Muttersprachler leicht feststellbar. Wenn ich merke, dass jemand Dialekt spricht, sehe ich in aller Regel von Korrekturen ab. Überhaupt korrigiere ich Muttersprachler ungern ungebeten, weil ich sonst nichts anderes mehr täte.

Comment: @Ad Infinitum, "ich denke, ich muss mehr betonen, dass ich es nicht persönlich nehme, wenn Sie mich korrigieren würden." ich würde es positiv formulieren, so wie Ludi vorgeschlagen hat. Also lieber sagen, dass man dankbar für Verbesserungen ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ich selber schreibe gelegentlich mit einer Freundin auf Russisch. Dabei kann ich wirklich nur bruchstückhaft diese Sprache und bin mir häufig sehr unsicher. Daher frage ich durchaus unmittelbar nachdem ich etwas geschrieben habe, wo ich mir unsicher bin, ob das richtig war bzw. wie es richtig wäre.

> War Какой richtig, oder hätte ich Который verwenden sollen?

Auf diese Weise signalisiere ich, dass ich gerne hier korrigiert werden möchte. Bei einer mündlichen Unterhaltung gibt es natürlich einfachere Möglichkeiten dies zum Ausdruck zu bringen.

> Какой..., ähm, (mit fragender Betonung:) Который

Somit kann ich also sofort Rückmeldung erhalten, wenn ich selber schon spüre, dass es falsch sein könnte. Außerdem vermittele ich, dass ich gewillt bin zu lernen und mich zu verbessern.

Wenn man dann beizeiten auch mal erwähnt, dass man gerne grundsätzlich korrigiert werden möchte, werden einige an der ein oder anderen Stelle dich korrigieren.

Das wird sich in aller Regel aber auf gröbere Fehler beziehen oder Fehler, die regelmäßig gemacht werden.
Beispielsweise kenne ich einige Nicht-Muttersprachler, die nur recht wenige Fehler machen. Da erübrigt es sich fast, Fehler zu korrigieren, da diese nicht von Bedeutung sind. Selbst wenn derjenige korrigiert werden möchte, empfände ich es eher als Störung einer fließenden Unterhaltung, wenn ich nun auf Nichtigkeiten eingehe. Hier würde ich erst bei krassen Fehlern korrigieren oder — wie oben erwähnt — am Rande mal bemerken, wenn jemand den immer gleichen Fehler macht.
Auf der anderen Seite gibt es Nicht-Muttersprachler, die in fast jedem Satz einen Fehler haben. In 99% der Fälle verstehe ich es trotzdem, aber ich würde im Leben nicht jeden Fehler korrigieren. In den seltenen Fällen, wo ich es gar nicht verstehe, frage ich sowieso nach und sobald ich verstanden habe, formuliere ich das einmal so, wie ich es ausgedrückt hätte.

Zurück zur Frage. Zusammenfassend kann man festhalten, dass du den Wunsch auf Korrektur äußern musst oder bei Unsicherheiten explizit die Korrektur anfragst. Ansonsten wird man dich nur korrigieren, wenn man dich nicht verstanden hat oder der Fehler schon sehr grob ist, obwohl du normalerweise gutes Deutsch sprichst.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Bestimmt werde ich mehr "signalisieren" :)

Comment: @Em1 ich habe "signalisieren"-Methode nach deiner Antwort benutzt und meine erste Korrektur bekommen:)

Comment: @AdInfinitum Du hast *die* "Signalisieren"-Methode benutzt und jetzt deine zweite Korrektur bekommen. Aber nenn es bitte nicht "Signalisieren"-Methode. Ich hätte an der Stelle auch gefühlt 10 andere Verben einsetzen können. Genau genommen war der Satz sowieso leicht gestelzt.